# Correctly using .AsParallel() efficiently with linq

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing

I have a tuple and I am iterating over it with LINQ

```
List<Tuple<string[], double[]>> tt = new List<Tuple<string[], double[]>>();

var t1 = new Tuple<string[], double[]>(
    new string[] { "java", "c#", "nn" },
    new double[] { 2, 3, 0 });

var t2 = new Tuple<string[], double[]>(
    new string[] { "java", "c#", "nn" },
    new double[] { 0, 3, 1 });

var t3 = new Tuple<string[], double[]>(
    new string[] { "java", "c#", "nn" },
    new double[] { 2, 1, 0 });

tt.Add(t1);
tt.Add(t2);
tt.Add(t3);  

var XX = (from tuples in tt
          let rows = tuples.Item2.ToArray()
          let result = rows.Select(x => x/rows.Count(i => i != 0)).ToArray()
         select new Tuple<string[], double[]>(tuples.Item1, result)
       ).ToList();
```

If I want to use the `.Asparallel` I can do one of the following ways:

I can added it when looping over the list:

```
        var XX = (from tuples in tt
                  .AsParallel() //Parallel added here
                  let rows = tuples.Item2.ToArray()
                  let result = rows.Select(x => x/rows.Count(i => i != 0)).ToArray()
                 select new Tuple<string[], double[]>(tuples.Item1, result)
               ).ToList();
```

I can add it when converting stuff using `.ToArray()` or `.ToList`

```
        var XX = (from tuples in tt

                  let rows = tuples.Item2.ToArray()
                  let result = rows.Select(x => x / rows.Count(i => i != 0)).AsParallel().ToArray() //Parallel added right here
                 select new Tuple<string[], double[]>(tuples.Item1, result)
               ).ToList();
```

What is the most efficient way to use `.Asparallel`? All of these methods give no errors but I am not sure if they effect performance.

And is adding `.Asparallel` like this a bad idea?:

```
        var XX = (from tuples in tt
                  .AsParallel() //added here
                  let rows = tuples.Item2.AsParallel().ToArray() //here
                  let result = rows.Select(x => x / rows.Count(i => i != 0)).AsParallel().ToArray()//here
                 select new Tuple<string[], double[]>(tuples.Item1, result)
               ).AsParallel().ToList(); // and here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `AsParallel` when starting your LINQ query, in `from` clause. That will make both `let` statements be executed in parallel and later on combined together when calling `ToList` at the end.

You can also add another `AsParallel` before calling `Select` inside the query.

```
var XX = (from tuples in tt.AsParallel()
          let rows = tuples.Item2.ToArray()
          let result = rows.AsParallel().Select(x => x/rows.Count(i => i != 0)).ToArray()
         select new Tuple<string[], double[]>(tuples.Item1, result)
       ).ToList();
```

However, you should remember that `AsParallel` has some overhead so in some cases it might be slower than regular, non-parallel processing. Depends on number of elements and how expensive the computation is.

Comment: It seems the overhead is not that costly expensive as the benefits is about twice as fast on duel core machines according to this:http://www.dotnetperls.com/asparallel but i find it messy to plaster it all over my code hence why I ask the question.